# PHP - file_get_contents doesn't get all contents (try with curl, same result)

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I try to get source code of a webpage.

```
$urlArena = 'http://arenavision.in/';
$suffixeSchedule = 'schedule';
$url = $urlArena.$suffixeSchedule;
//url = http://arenavision.in/schedule
$text = file_get_contents($url);
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
$text .= date('d-m-Y h:m:s'); 
fwrite($fp, $text);
fclose($fp);
```

I write it on a file to be sure of what contains var $text :

```
<html>
   <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <pre>
              //<![CDATA[
              try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=         
           [{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"aea30972f99dcd729c29d94acbb3cc58",petok:"87f9b51be2424b953e36dd5ec0f8ce1b0f74a3b5-1493799639-1800",zone:"arenavision.in",rocket:"a",apps:{}}];document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=85b614c0f6/cloudflare.min.js"><'+'\/script>');}}catch(e){};
//]]>
        </script>
        <script type="text/rocketscript">function set_cookie(){var now = new 
            Date();var time = now.getTime();time += 19360000 * 
            1000;now.setTime(time);document.cookie='beget=begetok'+'; 
            expires='+now.toGMTString()+'; path=/';}set_cookie();location.reload();;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
03-05-2017 08:05:46
</pre>
```

Is there a script on the webpage who cancel the function file_get_contents ?
Can I avoid it ?

I try with curl, but i get same result.
I try with another website (google.com), i was able to get all source code.

Thanks in advance for any help,

G.

Comment: Content is probably added using ajax / javascript. You could open the site and see what additional requests are made.

Comment: does that mean that if the ajax call were sync i could get the content ? i assume that call is async in this case.

Comment: No, that's not relevant. The browser starts loading new content as soon as the original content is retrieved so you would need to make the same  additional requests in order to get the same content. Your server does not process javascript so it will only get the original content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web site needs some cookies to fetch your desired page.

here is the scenario :

1) curl the first page `http://arenavision.in`

2) using regex get this value

```
document.cookie='beget=begetok'
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

3) send that cookies values to the next request.

---

Here is a quick example using `cURL` terminal commands:-

```
curl 'http://arenavision.in/'
```

Outputs:

```
<html><head><script>function set_cookie(){var now = new Date();var time = now.getTime();time += 19360000 * 1000;now.setTime(time);document.cookie='beget=begetok'+'; expires='+now.toGMTString()+'; path=/';}set_cookie();location.reload();;</script></head><body></body></html>
```

using the value of `document.cookie` in the next request will do the trick :

```
curl 'http://arenavision.in/' -H 'Cookie: beget=begetok'
```

Answer (score 1):

Content on this site generated dynamically. So you can't download full page that you can see in browser.

[image]

Anyway site protected by some cloud system. But you can provide cookie in your request to get full page:[image]

[image]

You have to emulate real user - add cookie in request, accept them before in first response. Use CURL to achieve it

Comment: Can i say to file_get_contents to wait a certain amount of time on the page for waiting that the dynamic part appear ?

Comment: @user2239695 Updated answer. You have to emulate real user - add cookie in request, accept them before in first response. Use CURL to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alex Slipknot and hassan.

Your both explaination help me a lot to understand.
So it works :)
Here is my final code :

```
$url = $urlArena.$suffixeSchedule;
$text = get_data($url);
$fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w');
$text .= date('d-m-Y h:m:s'); 
fwrite($fp, $text);
fclose($fp);

function get_data($url) {
$cookie = get_cookie($url);
if(!isset($cookie) || strlen($cookie) == 0)
{
    debug('error : '.$cookie.' strlen : '.strlen($cookie));
    return false;
}
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}

function get_cookie($url)
{
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
preg_match('/document.cookie=\'([^\']+)\'/',$data,$m);
print_r($m);
return $m[1];
}
```